# Splitting a string in the value attribute of Struts2 Iterator tag

Tags: regex, jsp, struts2, split

I am stuck at one point in my project and I need some help. Below is my requirement.

I have a string(for ex: exampleString) which I am storing in session as follows:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("exampleString",exampleString);
```

The exampleString will be like `abc|def|ghi|jkl`

Now in JSP I need to split it on "|" for using it in the Struts2 Iterator tag. For this I have written code as below:

```
<s:iterator var='item' value='#session.exampleString.split("|")'>
Remaining Code
</s:iterator>
```

Mow my problem is if I check the 'item' , the exampleString is not splitting up and the values that I am getting is `a b c | d e f | g h i | j k l`

I have also tried as follows:

```
<s:iterator var='item' value='#session.exampleString.split("\\|")'>
Remaining Code
</s:iterator>
```

The above code doesn't split the string at all.

I need to know where I am going wrong.

PS: This is my first post in this forum. Please let me know if I have done any mistakes while posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `\` as well so use:

```
<s:iterator var='item' value='#session.exampleString.split("\\\|")'>
  Remaining Code
</s:iterator>
```